# Why doesn't z-index work although with specified "position"?

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I have read that in order for z-index to take effect, the CSS elements involved need to have "position" attributes.  So I have a menu that I would like to appear over an IMG when someone clicks on the menu icon.  I have these styles for the menu and the image in the content area ...

```
.menu-btn div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    padding-right: 8px;
    margin-top: -0.50em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 200;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 99;
} 

#personImgDiv {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 80%;
}
```

However, when I click on the menu icon, the menu is still appearing behind the image -- https://jsfiddle.net/bdcmka1r/2/ .  What else am I missing?  How do I get the menu to always appear in front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're using the wrong selector. `.menu-btn` is the `button` class, and it will only affect this `button`, also there is no way a button can be treated as a container element such as div, nav, header ..etc. Your correct selector will be `nav` since your menu contained within `nav` tags. So, you need to add the `position` and `z-index` properties to `nav` selector instead.

```
nav {
  display: none;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  right: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  text-align: left; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#personImgDiv{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
header{
    z-index: 101;
}
```

I see. you have used z-index:100 in porosinIngDiv and you want to display menu over on image so you have to use z-index more in header then  #personImgDiv i have given answer on top it will more clear